# Can I connect multiple HC-05 to once Arduino board?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth

I am trying to automate my dorm room for the upcoming semester.  I have a bunch of arduino uno's lying around and I want to use them to control different appliances in the room, which I want to do via an IPhone app.  I found a few tutorials online about using an HC-05 but none explicitly say if I need more than one if I want to control different devices from the same app or really anything about controlling multiple devices with one app.

TL;DR  I want to control a bunch of devices from my phone, before I go out and buy the wrong parts what do I need and how do I connect multiple devices to one bluetooth device?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the HC05 module with an iPhone. Apple pushes BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy). If you were using an android app, it would work perfectly. My best advice would be to get one of [these](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1697). They work well with arduino. That one would connect to one arduino, and that arduino could be connected to multiple relays to control lights, fans, etc.

Comment: That module is deprecated in favour of these - https://www.adafruit.com/products/2479 (which are out of stock :( )  You can also use the HM-10 but the form-factor is less friendly - https://www.itead.cc/serial-port-ble-module-master-slave-hm-10.html